# How to track changes of environmental variables in linux?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, inotify

For the linux file systems there is inotify that helps to track file system events. Is there a similar mechanism to track changes of environmental variables?

Comment: Considering [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29176/108618), what is the point?

Comment: No, there is no standard mechanism to track changes of environmental variables.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski whole running in k8s a .net core app can detect the changes in config map thanks to I notify and the lib that consumes the inotify notifications, however the same is not true for env bars, the app once red parameters from the environment should rely on the the initial values.